# $\Pr(X>1.96)$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am trying to calculate $\Pr(X>1.96)$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Whether the answer can only be found in normal distribution table?

I took the $1.9$ column and move to the right to reach $0.06$ to get $0.9750$. I know it is the probability of $X<1.96$ (am I right?). So to calculate the $\Pr(X>1.96)$ I just do this : 
        $$\Pr(X>1.96) = 1 - \Pr(X<1.96) \implies \Pr(X>1.96) = 1-0.9750 = 0.025$$

I was wondering if this solution is correct?

Comment: The value you got for $\Pr(X > 1.96) = 0.025$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you @Nash J. Is this apply when we are looking for probabilities of a certain number? for instance, Pr(X=0) in the above example would be 0.5 based on the table. is that correct?

Comment: No because $X$ is continuous, so $P(X=a)$ is always 0 for any constant $a$.

Comment: In fact, $\Pr(X \geq 0) = 0.5$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you are correct.
Answer can not only be found in normal table, but also in Excel , Matlab, R etc

In excel   **=1-NORMSDIST(1.96)**   which gives  $0.024997895$
in R          **1 -pnorm(1.96,0,1)**   which gives $0.0249979$

similarly in other software.

Hope this was helpful .

Thanks

Comment: Can also use the distribution function of a normal